# How to add a logo to the header using deface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to add a header to the spree commerce website using deface. But the problem is logo is not getting loaded. I have tried the following ..

I have pasted the logo.png file in app/assets/images and in the config/initilazers/spree.rb

I have added `config.logo = 'logo.png'` in the block existing there.

This was not working, **so I added logo.png in the vendor/assets/images.(I created the images folder)**

This is the code I am having

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/_header',
    :name => 'Tryint to replace the header',
    :replace => 'div#spree-header',
    :text => '
             <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BIRTHDAY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ANNIVERSARY</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">WEDDING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CHRISTMAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CORPORATES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li> 
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
           '
             )
```

The above code file is present in the overrides/update_header.rb. It works fine except the logo does not show

Comment: is it correct path to `logo.png` ?

Comment: @IgorIvancha That is why I pasted logo file in two possible paths. Still it is not getting applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using img tag in html, instead of using image_tag as in rails way. And it should be like this `<%= image_tag("rails.png") %>` where rails.png is in app/assets/images